# Dynamically allocating memory without using malloc

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have been writing a program where I have a **2d array** that **changes size if the user wants**, as follows:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int max_length = 1024;
int memory_length = 16;
int block_length = 64;

void process_input(int memory[memory_length][block_length], char* user_input) {
    ...
}

int main(void) {
    printf("Not sure what to do? Enter 'help'\n");
    while (0 == 0) {
        int memory[memory_length][block_length];
        char user_input[max_length];
        printf(">> ");
        fgets(user_input, max_length, stdin);
        printf("\n");
        process_input(memory, user_input);
        if (user_input[0] == 'e' && user_input[1] == 'n' && user_input[2] == 'd') {
            break;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

NOTE: The process_input() function that I made allows the user to play around with the values inside the array 'memory' as well as change the value of **memory_length** or **block_length**, hence then changing the length of the array. After the user is done the cycle repeats with a fresh array.
I can use the 2d array perfectly fine, parsing it to any function. However one day I discover that there are functions such as malloc() that allow you to dynamically allocate memory through a pointer. This made me then question:

**Should I re-write my whole very complicated program to use malloc and other 'memory functions', or is it okay to keep it this way?**

Also as a side question that might be answered by answering the main question:

**Every time I declare the 2d array, does the previous contents of the array get free, or do I keep filling up my memory like an amateur?**

Finally if there is anything else that you may notice in the code or in my writing please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: The stack can be used for small memory allocations  but it is tiny compared to the amount of memory available using the heap through malloc.   Yes to using malloc, no to your code leaking memory because it is a local variable on the stack and the C library manages it.   Your homemade library might also be corrupting memory by going outside of the bounds of the memory that the c library allocated to you.

Comment: In your code, memory_length and block_length have value 0 by virtue of having static storage duration. That makes `int memory[memory_length][block_length];` a zero sized array. zero sized arrays are not allowed in C. Your code is broken. You need to rewrite it.

Comment: forgot about that, it is initially set to 64 and 16, thanks for letting me know

Comment: this is not 'dynamically allocated', its always the same size,

Comment: Now your memory array never changes size and is fine as long as you don't make it too big. (see @DaveS comment.). This still holds if you add code that changes the size before (re)declaring it. You are also inputting max_length after `char user_input[max_length];`, so that array is never the length you think it is (and is also on the stack). Outside of this, you can do this as long as the sizes are small enough and you are using a compiler that supports VLAs (VLA support is optional). This isn't really called dynamic memory allocation, though it does have the resemblance of runtime sizing.

Comment: You might need to pass block_length as a separate parameter to process_input() and probably want to pass memory_length also. I personally avoid using VLA's and am unsure of how to correctly pass a 2d array where both dimensions are variable to a function.

Comment: @DanielUman "have a 2d array that changes size if the user wants," is not technically possible in C.  Once an _array_ is defined, its size cannot change.  Code can _define_ a new array of various sizes, dynamically with VLA support.  But once defined, its size is fixed.  OTOH, code can change the amount of memory a pointer references, but that not an _array_, just a pointer to memory.

Comment: @AviBerger: The array dimensions need to be parameters prior to the array. So you could use a prototype like `SomeType processArray(int N, int M, int array[N][M]);` (adding more parameters at the beginning or end). This is actually pretty convenient, because it lets you use a natural subscripting syntax inside `processArray`. It's not necessary to allocate `array` as a VLA; you could allocate it with fixed dimensions, or dynamically-allocated with `int (*x)[M] = calloc(N, sizeof(*x))` (or variations on that theme).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I re-write my whole very complicated program to use malloc and other 'memory functions', or is it okay to keep it this way?

Probably rewrite it indeed. `int memory[memory_length][block_length];` in main() is a variable-length array (VLA). It is allocated with automatic storage and gets the size of those size variables at the point where its declaration is encountered, then it *can't* be resized from there.

For some reason a lot of beginners seem to think you can resize the VLA by changing the variables originally used to determine it's size, but no such magic relation between the VLA and those variables exists. [How to declare variable-length arrays correctly?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/283440)

The *only* kind of array in C that allows run-time resizing is one which was allocated dynamically. The only alternative to that is to allocate an array "large enough" and then keep track of how much of the array you actively are using - but it will sit there in memory (and that is likely no big deal).

However, it is not recommended to allocate huge arrays with automatic storage, since those usually end up on the stack and can cause stack overflows. Use either static storage duration or allocated storage (with malloc etc).

> Every time I declare the 2d array, does the previous contents of the array get free, or do I keep filling up my memory like an amateur?

You can only declare it once. In case you do so inside a local scope, with automatic storage duration, it does indeed get cleared up every time you leave the scope which it was declared. But that also means that it can't be used outside that scope.

> Finally if there is anything else that you may notice in the code or in my writing please let me know.

Yes, get rid of the global variables. There is no reason to use them in this example, avoid them like the plague. For example a function using an already allocated array might pass the sizes along, like in this example:

```c
void process_input (size_t memory_length, 
                    size_t block_length,
                    int    memory[memory_length][block_length], 
                    char*  user_input)
```

Answer (score -2):

In C, local variables, i.e. variables declared within a function, are allocated on the stack.  They are only allocated once when the function is first called.  The fact that you can declare variables within a while loop can lead to some confusion.  The loop does not somehow allocate the memory again and again.

The memory allocated for all local variables is released when the function return.

The main reason that you might want declare a variable inside a loop (besides convenience) is to limit the scope of the variable.  In your code above, you cannot access the "memory" variable outside of the while loop.  You can easily check this for yourself.  Your compiler should raise an error.

Whether the stack or the heap contains more memory depends on your computer architecture.  In an embedded system you can often specify whether to allocate more or less memory to the heap or the stack.  On a computer with virtual memory, such as a PC, the size of the heap and the stack are only limited by the size of your hard drive and the address space.

Allocating arrays on the heap is not as simple as it might seem.  Single dimensional arrays work just as you might imagine, but things get more complicated with multidimensional arrays, so it is probably better to stick with either a locally or statically declared array in your case.

Comment: *`In C, local variables, i.e. variables declared within a function, are allocated on the stack. They are only allocated once when the function is first called.`* it is wrong. They are created every time the function is called, not only the  first time

Comment: I believe that Linda means that sufficient memory is allocated all at once, once per call to the function. This is not guaranteed, but I believe how many/most implementations do work _except_ for VLAs. VLAs generally can't be handled that way and this question is all about VLAs. The VLAs will need to be reallocated each time through the loop as their size could change.

Comment: Linda "... declare variables within a while loop .... The loop does not somehow allocate the memory again and again." --> maybe it does.  C does not  specify - only lifetime and scope.

Comment: chux:  Yes, you are exactly right.  Compiler optimizations will typically avoid allocating and deallocating memory on the stack on each scope change since it requires more more code and it takes more time to do.